# Momentum-space entanglement entropy in CFT

Tags: entropy, conformal-field-theory

Is there any analytic formula known for the entanglement (entropy) in **momentum space** for conformal field theory like Calabrese-Cardy formula in position space?I’d like to know the how central charge is encoded in the expression of entanglement entropy in the momentum space.

Comment: What do you mean in momentum space? The entanglement entropy is not a function of any coordinates or momenta. It is a function of a geometrical region.

Comment: @MannyC I am considering the EE between the left-moving mode k and the right-moving mode -k for ψ(k), a wave function in the momentum space.